# Lake Edge Grasses

Tags: plant-recommendations, grass

I live on the edge of Clearlake in California. The lake rises and falls by as much as 6 to 10 feet per year. Therefore, about 2,000 to 3,000 square feet of my yard below my seawall is under water for about 6 to 8 months of the year. Is there any kind of grass, ideally with deep roots that I can plant when the area is relatively dry that can survive the Winter and Spring underwater?